# Error in voronoi diagram in Python with Scipy library

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, geopandas, voronoi

While plotting the Voronoi diagram in Python using the Scipy library, the output plot has the following two errors.

1. Lines are intersecting blue points (marked in red circle)
2. Background map (pink colored) is crossing the axis (marked in blue circle)

Following are the code lines.

```
  import matplotlib
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import geopandas as gpd
  import contextily as ctx
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

data_2 = r'F:\Python\Practice_Python\EVT\gas_nodes_nd_end.csv'
node_2 = pd.read_csv(data_2, sep=';', usecols= ['x', 'y'])

lon = node_2['x']
lat = node_2['y']

geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(node_2, geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(lon,lat))
array = geo_df[['x', 'y']].to_numpy()

map = gpd.read_file(r'F:\Python\Practice_Python\EVT\VG250_GEM.shp')
gap = map.to_crs("EPSG:25832")[(map.GEN == 'Bayreuth')]
vor = Voronoi(array)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
gap.plot(ax=ax, color='pink')

cat = voronoi_plot_2d(vor, ax=ax, show_vertices=True, line_colors='black', line_width=2, line_alpha=0.6,    point_size=10)

  plt.show()
```

[image: Output image of the code (Voronoi diagram)]

Kindly help to fix this problem.

Comment: *"Lines are intersecting blue points (marked in red circle)"* Look carefully at the numerical values of your points.  I suspect you have some pairs of points that are very close to each other.